# Remove MikTex from Ubuntu 18.04.2

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, dpkg, dependencies

How do I remove Miktex?  I need to remove MikkTex and install Texlive because of broken packages and updates issue.

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 miktex : Depends: libhunspell-1.3-0 (>= 1.3.3) but it is not installable
          Depends: libicu55 (>= 55.1-1~) but it is not installable
          Depends: libmpfr4 (>= 3.1.3) but it is not installable
          Depends: libpng12-0 (>= 1.2.13-4) but it is not installable
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution). 

and

Reading package lists... Done
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'http://miktex.org/download/ubuntu xenial InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'
```

Also

`` Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y (Reading database ... 284955 files and directories currently installed.) Removing miktex (2.9.6930-bionic1) ... miktexsetup: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4: version `CURL_OPENSSL_4' not found (required by /usr/bin/../lib/libMiKTeX209-packagemanager.so.5) dpkg: error processing package miktex (--remove): installed miktex package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1 Errors were encountered while processing: miktex E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1) ``

Comment: Does `sudo apt purge miktex` work?

Comment: No it does not work

Comment: all updates are also blocked until I fix the error.

Answer (score 4):

According to this [how-to](https://miktex.org/howto/miktex-console), before uninstalling MiKTeX you need to first reset your install to factory defaults using the MiKTeX console:

1. Launch the MiKTeX Console desktop application (search for "MiKTeX Console" in the application launcher).
2. Click "Cleanup" to navigate to the cleanup page.
3. Click "Reset the TeX installation" to factory defaults.

This resets the TeX installation to the initial state, deleting all the files and directories created by the MiKTeX installer. You can now uninstall via the command line:

```
sudo apt-get remove miktex
sudo apt autoremove
```