# remove miktex from terminal

Tags: 20.04, latex

I have installed MiKTeX on Ubuntu 20.04.2.

Unfortunately, I have upgraded MiKTeX and now Ubuntu is not booting; I would like to uninstall MiKTeX now.
In this discussion, instructions are given [Remove MikTex from Ubuntu 18.04.2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1130137/remove-miktex-from-ubuntu-18-04-2), however, I cannot access the console, hence I would need also to "Reset the TeX installation" (point 2 and 3 of the answer) by using commands in the terminal.
Could somebody help me?
Please consider that I am an Ubuntu neophyte.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: How exactly did you installed MiKTeX?

Comment: I followed the instructions here: https://miktex.org/howto/install-miktex-unx
Anyway, the installation went fine, I also edited my latex document. The point is that I did not use a basic configuration but I  upgraded (upgrade option at the end of the page).

Comment: Thank you, I am not sure it worked properly as I can still only access the terminal of UBUNTU. I will update the comment once I managed to boot it normally.

Comment: Miktex was correctly removed. Thank you.

Comment: I am having the same kind of issue: https://askubuntu.com/q/1507954/947071

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to boot to recovery mode from GRUB, then choose

> ```
> network    Enable Networking
> ```

and then

> ```
> root       Drop to root shell
> ```

and finally execute the following commands in root shell to remove MikTex:

```
mv /etc/apt/sources.list.d/miktex.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/miktex.list.save
apt-get update
apt-get autopurge miktex

rm -rfv /usr/libexec/miktex
rm -rfv /var/lib/miktex-texmf
rm -rfv /var/cache/miktex-texmf
rm -rfv /var/log/miktex
rm -rfv /usr/local/share/miktex-texmf
rm -v /etc/fonts/conf.d/09-miktex.conf

apt-get install tree
cd /usr/local/bin
rm -v $(tree | grep miktex | awk '{print $2}')
rm -v *latex
```

and to fix the system using same root shell:

```
apt-get dist-upgrade
apt-get install -f
dpkg --configure -a
```

and then reboot to normal system.

Also please note that usage of [TeXLive from official Ubuntu repositories](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/texlive-full) is more comfortable and reproducible than using MikTex from third-party site.