# MiKTeX Console has closed unexpectedly in Ubuntu 22.04 and switching to TeXLive

Tags: latex, texlive, miktex

I have been using MiKTeX in my Ubuntu machine for a long time without any problem. But today, I faced a problem after compiling my document with a new package. This is what appeared:
[image]

Relaunching MiKTeX didn't help. I guessed I might need to open the MiKTeX Console and install the package first. But the console was not opening.

Using `initexmf --report> miktex-report.txt`, the following report is generated:

```
ReportDate: 2024-03-19 12:56:57
CurrentVersion: 24.3
SetupDate: 2024-03-19 10:48:00
SetupVersion: 24.3
Configuration: Regular
GitInfo: a0a66a1 / 2024-03-09 11:57:13
OS: Linux 6.5.0-26-generic #26~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Tue Mar 12 10:22:43 UTC 2 x86_64
SharedSetup: no
LinkTargetDirectory: /home/rafi/bin
PathOkay: yes
LastUpdateCheck: 2024-03-03 19:26:53
LastUpdate: 2024-03-02 15:28:29
LastUpdateDb: 2024-03-03 19:26:45
SystemAdmin: no
RootPrivileges: no
AdminMode: no
Root0: /home/rafi/.miktex/texmfs/config
Root1: /home/rafi/.miktex/texmfs/data
Root2: /home/rafi/.miktex/texmfs/install
UserInstall: /home/rafi/.miktex/texmfs/install
UserConfig: /home/rafi/.miktex/texmfs/config
UserData: /home/rafi/.miktex/texmfs/data
```

And `latex --version` shows:

```
MiKTeX-pdfTeX 4.19 (MiKTeX 24.3)
© 1982 D. E. Knuth, © 1996-2023 Hàn Thế Thành
TeX is a trademark of the American Mathematical Society.
using bzip2 version 1.0.8, 13-Jul-2019
compiled with curl version 7.81.0; using libcurl/7.81.0 OpenSSL/3.0.2 zlib/1.2.11 brotli/1.0.9 zstd/1.4.8 libidn2/2.3.2 libpsl/0.21.0 (+libidn2/2.3.2) libssh/0.9.6/openssl/zlib nghttp2/1.43.0 librtmp/2.3 OpenLDAP/2.5.17
compiled with expat version 2.4.7; using expat_2.4.7
compiled with jpeg version 80.0
compiled with liblzma version 50020052; using 50020052
compiled with libpng version 1.6.37; using 1.6.37
compiled with MiKTeX Application Framework version 4.8; using 4.8
compiled with MiKTeX Core version 4.24; using 4.24
compiled with MiKTeX Archive Extractor version 4.1; using 4.1
compiled with MiKTeX Package Manager version 4.10; using 4.10
compiled with openssl version OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022; using OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022
compiled with uriparser version 0.9.6
compiled with xpdf version 4.04
compiled with zlib version 1.2.11; using 1.2.11
```

The problem is issued on GitHub as well: https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/1468

But I need a quick fix for now. How can I fix it?

Should I move to TeXLive?

According to the official doc (https://miktex.org/howto/miktex-console), I need to reset the TeX installation to the initial state using the `Cleanup` in the MiKTeX Console. Then I can uninstall it. But the Console is not opening. Then what should I do?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/q/1358106/947071